# Что возвращает данная функция в JS?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Разбираюсь в opensource проекте и вновь возник непонятный момент. Что возвращает функция? Что данный синтаксис в себе подразумевает?

> return {
>               receive: receive 
>           };

```
  function TextReceiver(connection) {
        var content = {};

        function receive(data, userid, extra) {
            // uuid is used to uniquely identify sending instance
            var uuid = data.uuid;
            if (!content[uuid]) {
                content[uuid] = [];
            }

            content[uuid].push(data.message);

            if (data.last) {
                var message = content[uuid].join('');
                if (data.isobject) {
                    message = JSON.parse(message);
                }

                // latency detection
                var receivingTime = new Date().getTime();
                var latency = receivingTime - data.sendingTime;

                var e = {
                    data: message,
                    userid: userid,
                    extra: extra,
                    latency: latency
                };

                if (connection.autoTranslateText) {
                    e.original = e.data;
                    connection.Translator.TranslateText(e.data, function(translatedText) {
                        e.data = translatedText;
                        connection.onmessage(e);
                    });
                } else {
                    connection.onmessage(e);
                }

                delete content[uuid];
            }
        }

        return {
            receive: receive //в этом месте мне непонятно
        };
    }
```

Comment: Возвращает объект, у которого есть свойство `receive`, который равен функции `receive`. Например `{receive: function receive(data, userid, extra){...}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае создается литерал объекта:

`{...}`

В создаваемом объекте указано свойство: `receive:`

Далее указано значение для этого свойства: `receive` - функция объявленная выше.

Подробнее о [способах инициализации объекта](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)